# Triggering mysql delete in another table?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, sql-delete

I have 3 tables in my database:

```
|    systems  |
|-------------|
|  system_id  |
|-------------|

|   systems_maintenances  |
|-------------------------|
|  systems_maintenances_id|
|  system_id              |
|  maintenance_id         |
|-------------------------|


|        maintenances     |
|-------------------------|
|  maintenance_id         |
|-------------------------|
```

I'd like that when I delete a system, the `maintenance` being deleted too.
For the moment it only deletes in the `systems_maintenances` table.

I think a trigger is the best (and only?) way to do that.
I created this one:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `deleteMaintenance` BEFORE DELETE ON `systems`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  DELETE FROM maintenances
  WHERE maintenance_id = systems_maintenances.maintenance_id;
END
```

The problem is I get the error:

> DELETE FROM  `SNMProject`.`systems` WHERE  `systems`.`system_id` =16
>
> MySQL a répondu:
>
> #1054 - Unknown column 'systems_maintenances.maintenance_id' in 'where clause

How to solve my problem?

I don't know if it can help but I have this too for the `systems_maintenances` table:

[image: test]
<sub>(source: [xooimage.com](http://img110.xooimage.com/files/4/6/c/systems_maintenances-4754a0c.png))</sub>

Comment: Trigger is not the solution, DELETE CASCADE is the one. See http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/

Answer (score 1):

In a trigger, you don't refer to the *table name* of the table being affected.  Instead, you refer to a proxie for it.  That proxie depends on the database.  In MySQL, it is `new` and `old`.

I suspect that you want something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `deleteMaintenance` BEFORE DELETE ON `systems` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
          DELETE FROM maintenances m
          WHERE maintenance_id IN (SELECT maintenance_id
                                   FROM systems_maintenances sm
                                   WHERE systems_maintenances.system_id = old.system_id
                                  )
END;
```

There are other ways to express this logic, but this gives a good idea of the structure.

You can do essentially the same thing using cascading deletes, if you prefer.  That way, you don't have to write triggers and can put the logic in the `create table` statement.